# Splitting a number over several ranges

Tags: c#, algorithm, random, numbers, distribution

I am trying to split a number into smaller numbers that fit predefined ranges and I can't seem to get the algorithm right. I am using C#.

**Example**

Split **20** into **three** numbers where the numbers have to fit the following ranges: **1-3, 3-10, and 0-15**. Final numbers could look like this: 1,5,14 or 2,3,15

Another example could be to split **100** into four numbers that fit the following ranges: **0-10, 0-10, 0-40, 0-40**. The result would naturally be 10,10,40,40. Splitting 90 on the same ranges could result 5,8,38,39 etc.

Can you kick me in the right direction?

(no, it's not a homework, it's for a personal project)

Comment: I'd be looking into change calculator applications code; even if the goal is not exactly the same, you might find some ideas !

Comment: Are the ranges always going to be sequential?

Comment: Yes, it is always the min and the max allowed number

Comment: How about, get the minimums for each range, sort them, and then subtract from a running total of the number to be split as you take each minimum, if there is left over total, add to the minimums until the running total is 0?

Comment: Should the code return random numbers that satisfy the condition? Or is it ok if it always returns the same values for the same given number and ranges?

Comment: It should always return random numbers

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using recursion.

The idea of the algorithm is something like this:

- In every execution you're going to iterate through all possible numbers of the interval.
- Calls recursive to generate the next number of the next interval.
- If at any time the sum passes the desired value then backtracks.
- Once all the numbers are generated, if the sum is equal to the desired number then you have a possible combination.

It can be improved but it is a solution.

The following code prints all valid sequences in the console:

```
SplitNumber(100, new Interval[]
{
    new Interval { Min = 0, Max = 11 },
    new Interval { Min = 0, Max = 11 },
    new Interval { Min = 0, Max = 40 },
    new Interval { Min = 0, Max = 40 },
});

public static void SplitNumber(int n, Interval[] intervals)
{
    SplitNumber(n, 0, intervals, "");
}

public static void SplitNumber(int n, int k, Interval[] intervals, string s)
{
    if (n < 0) return;

    if (k >= intervals.Length) { if (n == 0) Console.WriteLine(s); }
    else
        for (int i = intervals[k].Min; i <= intervals[k].Max; i++)
            SplitNumber(n - i, k + 1, intervals, string.Format("{0} {1}", s, i));
}
```

`Interval` class is something like this:

```
public class Interval
{
    public int Min { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach since it is possible to get basically any possible variation. The solution is a bit heavy however since it has go through all the intervals. Thanks a lot, it's a great idea!

Answer (score 1):

The following describes a pretty efficient approach, assuming that the buckets have some sort of ordering.

Start by choosing the minimum value for each range and adding them up.

- If the sum is equal to your number, then stop.
- If the sum is greater then your number, then issue an error.
- If the sum is less than your number, then continue.

Next, subtract the minimum value from each range so they are all normalized on 0 . . n and subtract the sum from your number.  This isn't strictly necessary, but it helps with the explanation of the rest of the algorithm.

Next, do a cumulative sum of the max range values.  Find the bucket where your new sum fits in (too big for the previous bucket but fits in).  If none are found, then issue an error.

Then allocate the bins so the preceding buckets are at their maximum and set the one found to the appropriate value.

This gives you one set of values that meet your conditions.

If you want values more in the "middle" of the ranges, then start with the middle value of the ranges.  Then add or subtract values in chunks across all buckets, until you hit the maximum.  This requires a little more iteration, but it is also quite efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> ranges = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
ranges.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 3));
ranges.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 3));
ranges.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1, 100));

int totalSum = ranges.Sum(i => i.Value - i.Key);

double ws = 0.0;
int rIndex = 0;
var rangeAndWeight = ranges.Select(i => new { index = rIndex++, range = i, maxw = (ws += (double)(i.Value - i.Key) / totalSum) }).ToList();

int[] nums = ranges.Select(i => i.Key).ToArray();

int number = 50;

Random r = new Random();
while (nums.Sum() != number)
{
    double rDouble = r.NextDouble();

    var index = rangeAndWeight.SkipWhile(i => i.maxw < rDouble).First().index;

    if (nums[index] < ranges[index].Value)
        nums[index] += 1;
}
```

`nums` array contains smaller numbers you need

Comment: This is something that did not cross my mind, thanks for the input. It seems that this solution will however suffer from the problem that the smaller ranges will get filled in faster than the bigger ones which might not lead to a truly random distribution. Am I right? For example, let's say the ranges are 1-3,1-3, and 1-100. Number being distributed is 50. It will almost always result in 3,3, and 44.

Comment: I've edited the answer. May be it is not optimal, but it looks like to work properly

Comment: And another one correction. Because the 1st and the 2nd ranges are the same, the 2nd one was never selected. Now it is fixed

Comment: Yes, the previous version wasn't working properly. I am testing this one now. It still is not completely random since it's fairly hard to get the extremes with this algorithm (e.g. distribute 50 over 1-40,1-40,1-20 will basically always yield values around 20,20,10) but it is a pretty okay stab at the problem. Thanks a bunch so far!

Comment: running this code for more than 20 times, a got 20,20,10 only once

Comment: I am not saying exactly 20,20,10 but around those values. It's rather rare to get 40,1,9 with this algorithm if I am not mistaken. Don't get me wrong, I am not dissing your implementation, I am very happy with your contribution. I will do more testing tomorrow.

Comment: That's ok, no problem. And I think you are right, I think the result will be more evenly distributed with this code, more smoothed, which is not your case, I suppose :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104513/discussion-between-kraken-and-vdn).

Answer (score 0):

You could write a programm that just tries to sum up possible numbers in the allowed range and hopes that the result is correct and backtracks if the result is wrong. Its pretty inefficent tho ...

Comment: This seems like it should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: @Pseudonym It's a valid random variate generation technique known as "acceptance/rejection."  The fact that it doesn't take long to describe doesn't alter its legitimacy.

Comment: If the combination of values of the ranges is too big and the valid combinations too small, it could really take some time. Besides, that's now how you are supposed to code. :P